# gcov to ignore standard library branch?

Tags: gcc, gcov

I'm trying to use gcov/lcov to generate a report for my test suites for my source code. Is there a way to tell gcov to ignore the branches incurred by standard libraries. For example, stringstream

```
                     :          2 :             std::stringstream myss;
 156 [ +  - ][ +  - ]:          1 :             myss << "Testing" << std::endl;
```

Also, I use namespace in all of my source files. At the end of the file, gcov would report thre are branches. Where are those branches coming from ?

```
     [ +  - ][ +  - ]:          7 : } // end namespace
     [ +  - ][ +  - ]
     [ +  - ][ +  - ]
```

Thank you very much for any input!

Comment: This branch is not from standard library, it is from inlining of template code (first fragment) or from destructors (second fragment). You can try to disable inlining to get less *strange* branches in middle of your code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Did you mean -fno-inline ? I tried that and the number of strange branches seem to be the same.